# Cron script executed but no output

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I've taken a look to many different topics and did not find an answer to my problem. I created 2 bash scripts on my Ubuntu server and I'm trying to execute them periodically. It seems they are running, but they produce nothing. They are executable:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Mar 14 18:02 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2623 Apr 16 21:18 backup.pl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 87066352 May 10 21:37 full_site_backup-10-4-2018.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      530 May 11 20:21 checkHealth.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 May 11 20:35 .
```

So here is one of my scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

# log stdout and stderr to two different files
exec >>/var/log/test.log 2>>/var/log/test.err.log

# ...and log every command we try to execute to stderr (aka looog.err.log)
# set -x

CODE=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -I -A "myuseragent" -w "%{http_code}" https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxxx)

DATE=$(date)

if [ $CODE -gt 300 ]
then
    service mysql restart
    service tomcat8 restart
    >&2 echo "$DATE - KO !!!!!! code retour $CODE"
else
    echo "$DATE - OK, code $CODE"
fi
```

and here is my `sudo crontab -e` :

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 2 * * * root /usr/bin/perl /var/backup/backup.pl
* * * * * root /bin/sh /var/backup/checkHealth.sh
```

and here is my `sudo tail -f /var/log/cron.log`:

```
May 11 20:39:01 ns381471 CRON[10778]: (root) CMD (root /bin/sh /var/backup/checkHealth.sh)
May 11 20:39:26 ns381471 crontab[10823]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
May 11 20:40:01 ns381471 CRON[10880]: (root) CMD (root /bin/sh /var/backup/checkHealth.sh)
May 11 20:40:01 ns381471 CRON[10879]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
May 11 20:40:30 ns381471 crontab[10823]: (root) END EDIT (root)
May 11 20:41:01 ns381471 CRON[10974]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
May 11 20:41:01 ns381471 CRON[10975]: (root) CMD (root /bin/sh /var/backup/checkHealth.sh)
May 11 20:42:01 ns381471 CRON[11070]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
May 11 20:42:01 ns381471 CRON[11071]: (root) CMD (root /bin/sh /var/backup/checkHealth.sh)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And have you checked the two log files `/var/log/test.log` and `/var/log/test.err.log`? Also be aware that you're executing the script with `/bin/sh` while its `#!`-line says `/bin/bash`. _Also_ you output the `curl` result to `/dev/null` so `$CODE` will most likely be empty.

Comment: Do they work if you run them manually? Can you add more debug output, e.g. a message before the curl command, and maybe another message afterwards which includes the result?

Comment: Hold on, are you waiting on a terminal and expecting the output of the cron to appear there ? Where exactly are you expecting the output ?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I think -o and -w operate independently: -o sends the (-I) response header to devnull, but the reponse code still goes to stdout.

Comment: Well, when I execute these scripts manually they work as expected. One writes to the log files, and the other uploads a backup tar.gz to my google drive. From the cron task they do nothing, at least they seem to do nothing.

Comment: Modify your crontab to capture the output, if any.  So `* * * * * COMMAND >/tmp/out1.txt 2>/tmp/out2.txt`.  Then review the out files.

Comment: thanks @Nic3500 for the tip, it gave me the right thing to focus on : `/bin/sh: root: command not found`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for those who are in the same situation, my crontab was

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 2 * * * root /usr/bin/perl /var/backup/backup.pl
* * * * * root /bin/sh /var/backup/checkHealth.sh
```

It appears that I just copied the syntax you can find on many cron tutorials about editing `/etc/crontab`, but in my case I did a `sudo crontab -e`, so I did not have to specifiy the user (root), so the working entries were :

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 2 * * * /usr/bin/perl /var/backup/backup.pl
* * * * * /bin/sh /var/backup/checkHealth.sh
```

or simplier :

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 2 * * * /var/backup/backup.pl
* * * * * /var/backup/checkHealth.sh
```